# A/B testing on sparse metrics

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ab-test

Out of my entire population(in this case all the possible posts) only .05% of my posts will be liked.

I introduce a new post format, and design an A/B test to test my old post format to see if my new post format will be better than my old post format in terms of likes received. We can set this as say 5% better than my original.

Since in general very few people would like any posts in general, how do I design a test and make sure my difference didn't come from a sampling error? Can I even apply the central limit theorem and do a parametric test in this case, what I'm measuring is so sparse?

Comment: Just to clarify you want to test if the percentage of posts being liked will be different between the two variants A and B.

Comment: Yes, I'm also curious if you can test for the difference in average amount of likes between A and B. Because one of the variants may contain a post that naturally attracts a lot of likes due to content and not design. Since the metric we're measuring is so sparse relative to the entire population, I'm wondering if we can still apply the CLT and do a parametric test.